# RecyclerView List and intent to next activity Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have created a list using `RecyclerView` and I want that if a user touches on an item in that list, it will redirect user to another `activity`.Noted that I have `list` in a `tab`. How to achieve this ? Here is what I have tried so far.

1. **class List Adapter**

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements View.OnClickListener 
{

```
List<ListName> mItems;
public ListAdapter(FragmentActivity c) {
    super();
    mItems = new ArrayList<ListName>();

    ListName nature = new ListName();
    nature.setName("Jose Mourinho");
    nature.setDes("Chelsea Football Club");
    mItems.add(nature);

    nature = new ListName();
    nature.setName("Louis van Gaal");
    nature.setDes("Manchester United");
    mItems.add(nature);

    nature = new ListName();
    nature.setName("Arsene Wenger");
    nature.setDes("Arsenal");
    mItems.add(nature);

    nature = new ListName();
    nature.setName("Manuel Pellegrini");
    nature.setDes("Manchester City");
    mItems.add(nature);

    nature = new ListName();
    nature.setName("Brendan Rodgers");
    nature.setDes("Liverpool CF");
    mItems.add(nature);
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyler_view_list, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    ListName nature = mItems.get(i);
    viewHolder.tvName.setText(nature.getName());
    viewHolder.tvDes.setText(nature.getDes());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

    return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView tvName;
    public TextView tvDes;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        tvDes = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);
    }
    }

    }
```

2. **class ListName** . This class is used to set and get the name and description

   ```
     public class ListName {
       private String mName;
       private String mDes;

      public String getName() {
      return mName;
    }
      public void setName(String name) {
   this.mName = name;
     }
      public String getDes() {
       return mDes;
     }
      public void setDes(String des) {
       this.mDes = des;
     }

     }
   ```
3. **class Tab1**. This is a `fragment` class for Tab1.

   ```
    public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container,      false);
   final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
   final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
   LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(c);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           final ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(c);
           c.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
               }
           });
       }
   }).start();

   return view;
   }
   }
   ```
4. **class ViewPagerAdapter** . This class is `adapter` for tabs

   ```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[]; 
    int NumbOfTabs; 


   public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
   super(fm);

   this.Titles = mTitles;
   this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {

   if (position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
   {
       Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
       return tab1;
   } else             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
   {
       Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
       return tab2;
   }

   }

   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return Titles[position];
   }
   ```

   // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

   ```
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
     return NumbOfTabs;
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Put a setOnClickListener on your itemView in your Viewholder and write the code to go to another activity (intent)

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

public TextView tvName;
public TextView tvDes;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) 
    {
        super(itemView);
        tvName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        tvDes = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);

        itemView..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ActivityName.class);
                     startActivity(intent); //or startActivityForResult(REQUEST, intent);
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: I've got errors at getActivity().getApplicationContext and startActivity(intent). This is because it can't resolve the getActivity and startActivity. How to solve it? Thanks

Comment: It's getActivity().getApplicationContext() with brackets.. (or maybe you can try ActivityName.this instead)
and normally resolving startActivity shouldn't give problems

Comment: I have tried it, but it still show an error 'Cannot resolve method getActivity()' is there anything that I haven't applied?

Comment: you need to use getActivity().getApplicationContext() inside a fragment to get the context of the activity. When you are in your activity, then you just can use 'this' to call it's context